# My head has no face

Tags: riddle

My head has no face,
but I breathe and bleed.
I am quiet,
but my visitors love to sing.

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll throw my hat into the ring. The first line is a stretch, but the others fit well.

> A Tree

My head has no face,

> Trees are sometimes compared to old men (Old Man Willow), but do not have human faces.

but I breathe and bleed.

> Plants can 'breath' using processes such as photosynthesis and respiration. Trees bleed sap.

I am quiet,

> Trees don't make noise on their own.

but my visitors love to sing.

> Birds nest in trees, and many love to sing.

......

Comment: Plants don't inhale Carbondioxide and exhale oxygen while breathing. Its the opposite! BTW, nice answer.

Comment: You are correct sir.  And yes, trees have a head, you can google "head of the tree".

Comment: @CoolGuy You actually are wrong, but you are correct. Trees also inhale oxygen at night and exhale carbon-dioxide. At least that's what I've always learned at school.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, you are correct. Plants convert CO2 to O2 when there is light, and O2 to CO2 when there is no light. The first is called "photosynthesis" and the second is called "respiration".

Comment: @JLRishe It's always good to know that I'm correct. Lets just see if this will be addressed in the answer (as it should).

Comment: Cool! Thanks for posting these riddles. They're fun. I've updated my answer in regards to breathing.

Answer (score 11):

My guess (yes, I love answering your riddles...)

> Microphone

My head has no face:

> The top of the microphone is considered the head.

but I breathe and bleed.

> There's a such thing as microphone bleed, and I'm guessing the mesh is the 'breathe' part.

I am quiet:

> Microphones by themselves don't make noise

but my visitors love to sing.

> Microphones are used generally for singing (karaoke, anyone?)

Even if it's not the right answer, it makes sense to me (I'm a musician by hobby).

Comment: Yes it makes sense, and a very clever answer.  Correct me if I am wrong, it is the audio signal that can bleed into another channel, not the microphone directly, right?

Comment: You know what, I googled microphone bleed.  You are right.  I have a different answer in mind, but yours is also correct because it satisfies all requirements, except breathe.. so I can't award you.

Comment: Microphone bleed is when it picks up unwanted sounds (you're recording something, and it picks up the car driving past, for an extreme example).

Comment: I am impressed very much with your answer, though!

Comment: Oh and thanks for your comment about my riddles, I am enjoying it too. :-)

Comment: Sure thing! I have to do something to keep my brain fresh, and thinking outside the box here (especially with your riddles), is helping! :p

Answer (score 2):

I was convinced it was

> a shower

My head has no face,

> obviously a shower head has no face

but I breathe and bleed.

> all showers dispense water (bleed) and some have additional hot air jets (breathe)

I am quiet,
but my visitors love to sing.

> who doesn't sing in the shower?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking it might be

> "a glass of beer."
>
>  Beer's foam is commonly called a "head."
>
> Beer breathes and bleeds - it "breathes" because of the bubbles, and "bleeds" when someone takes a sip.
>
> Beer itself is quiet, but in a pub, where there's lots of drinking, there might be singing.

That's my take - good riddle!